# Do I ever have to check for a pointer validity on this method?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class A
{
private:
    A(){}; 
    ~A(){};
public:
    static A* GetInstance( void )
    {
        static A obj;
        return& obj;
    }
};
```

I was supposing if something `bad` happens would only happen at the first time, since the class constructor is only initialized the first time a call to `GetInstance` happens, I don't know the great depths of C++ and I do not trust C++, so when I need a pointer to this class that will be used many times in a function I'm currently doing:

```
A* ptr = A::GetInstance();
if( ptr )
{
```

Checking for the pointer validity, I **believe** that the method returns the address where the value of `obj` is stored so that `ptr` will point to it, which I guess it `can't` fail.

Please observe that I'm not talking about a small application, I'm currently developing on a 500,000+ lines MMO server application that handles thousand of clients and has to stay opened for weeks without crashing, defensive programming is the least minimum required. Is it for **sure**, **100%** safe to use `ptr` without checking its validity?

Comment: `and I do not trust C++` for shame... trust the language, love the language.

Comment: @Mike: He's right not to trust C++ when it comes to managing the lifetimes of static objects. That is fraught with hidden dangers.

Comment: If you don't trust the language to give you a valid pointer when it's required to do so, then can you really trust it to properly check that the pointer is valid, either?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well you can trust C++ to do exactly what it says it's going to do, no more and no less.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: As long as you understand all the implications of what it says. For example, this doesn't say that it will always return a pointer to a valid object, but it might look like it does to someone who doesn't know all the ins and outs of object lifetimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is certainly no way that that function will ever return a null pointer, so there's no point checking for that. It might make more sense to return a reference, to make it clear that it won't be null.

However, there's no guarantee that the function will always return a pointer to a valid object. If it's called from the destructor of a static object, then `obj` might already have been destroyed. This is one reason why globally accessible objects are a very bad idea, whether or not you wrap them up in the Singleton anti-pattern like this.

Comment: Hey mike, problem about returning a  reference is that if the deconstructor is private you cant `A ref = A::GetInstance()`, assuming the method is `A& GetInstance() { static A obj; return obj; }`

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: No, but you could do `A & ref = A::GetInstance();`

Comment: Oh yes +1, I was making a wrong usage of the reference return.

Answer (score 2):

The function will always return a pointer to an object that exists. The only danger is if the object itself is invalid, and this should have been indicated by a throw from the object constructor. In your case you do not catch an exception from the constructor so the program should halt in that case, otherwise it should be good to go.

Checking for `NULL` is pointless because you always return a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a check for the pointer is unlikely to cause significant performance degradation but should be unnecessary. Add it if it will make you feel better. However, I would be more concerned about buffer overflows, memory leaks and other more likely issues than whether the `static` keyword is implemented by the compiler correctly.